# Log In problems outside VM

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, tuleap

I've recently installed Tuleap on a CentOS VM running on VMWare. Everything works OK in the VM, but when I try to log in outside the VM (My physical computer) the log in doesn't work, the page is unavailable.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your host can't resolve the name of your virtual machine.

You can probably fix it by ensuring that the virtual machine is using bridged rather than NAT networking, and by putting an entry for the virtual machine in the hosts file on your physical computer.

I hope this helps